# Can someone explain how chained functions work when there is a prototype function in the chain in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, superagent

I'm trying to separate the chained calls from:

```
request
  .post('/upload')
  .attach('image1', 'path/to/felix.jpeg')
  .attach('image2', imageBuffer, 'luna.jpeg')
  .field('caption', 'My cats')
  .end(callback);
```

to:

```
request
  .post('/upload')

request
  .attach('image1', 'path/to/felix.jpeg')
  .attach('image2', imageBuffer, 'luna.jpeg')
  .field('caption', 'My cats')
  .end(callback);
```

I'm probably thinking about this wrong and missing a concept, but I would like to know why that doesn't work and how does `.attach` (being a function added to the prototype of request) does get called in the first instance. And any pointers to any resources

Ref:
https://github.coventry.ac.uk/askaria/304CEM-LizoFile/blob/master/node_modules/superagent/docs/index.md#attaching-files

https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request.post()` call is actually returning something and then the next method `.attach()` is called on that returned data.

You can use

```
const req = request
  .post('/upload');

req
  .attach('image1', 'path/to/felix.jpeg')
  .attach('image2', imageBuffer, 'luna.jpeg')
  .field('caption', 'My cats')
  .end(callback);
```